# Spotify: embed player with multiple playlists

Tags: spotify, libspotify

I would like to embed a Spotify player with 3 or 4 Spotify playlists, not just one. How?

Any feedback highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using [Spotify Widgets](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/widgets/) - this isn't possible at the moment. You can either build your own widget using the [Spotify Web API](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/) or embed multiple widgets on your page, one per playlist.